# How to spawn urdf.xacro-file into Gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I've build a robot model with urdf. Additional I've used some macros to reduce my code. The model is working in rviz too. But if I want to spawn my robot into Gazebo, it doesn't work. After removing each macro, I can spawn my model into Gazebo. Is there a way to use my first robot model directly in Gazebo? How can I design my own color in Gazebo. Something like this

```
  <gazebo reference="name_of_link">
    <material name="Green">
      <color rgba="0.0 0.8 0.0 1.0"/>
    </material>
  </gazebo>
```

doesn't work. Many thanks for your help!!!

Now I have a new problem:-( Since the usage of macros still doesn't work, I removed the macros and buil my new robot model bit by bit. But from a certain number of model parts the process of spawning a model is successful but you can't see a model in Gazebo although the robot is listed in the model list. Any ideas?

While spawning I get no errors on the terminal. Here is a part of my code.

```
<!-- Motorhalterung -->
<link name="motor_holder">
        <inertial>
                    <mass value="1.0" />
                <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0"  ixz="0"
                     iyy="1" iyz="0"
                         izz="1" />
        </inertial> 
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.03 0.09 0.07"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Dark_Grey">
            <color rgba="0.3 0.3 0.3 1"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.03 0.09 0.07"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
</link>

<joint name="chassis_to_motor_holder" type="fixed">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="motor_holder"/>
  <origin xyz="0.09 0 ${chassis_height/2 + 0.07/2}"/>
    </joint>

    <gazebo reference="motor_holder">
        <material>ETABot/Dark_Grey</material>
    </gazebo>

    <!-- Motor -->
<link name="motor">
        <inertial>
                    <mass value="1.0" />
                <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0"  ixz="0"
                     iyy="1" iyz="0"
                         izz="1" />
        </inertial> 
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.09" radius="0.03"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <material name="Blue" />
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.06" radius="0.03"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </collision>
</link>

<joint name="motor_holder_to_motor" type="fixed">
  <parent link="motor_holder"/>
  <child link="motor"/>
  <origin xyz="-0.06 0 0"/>
    </joint>

    <gazebo reference="motor">
        <material>ETABot/Blue</material>
    </gazebo>

<!-- Motor -->
<link name="motor_controller">
        <inertial>
                    <mass value="1.0" />
                <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0"  ixz="0"
                     iyy="1" iyz="0"
                         izz="1" />
        </inertial> 
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.05 0.05 0.03"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue" />
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.05 0.05 0.03"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
</link>

<joint name="chassis_to_motor_controller" type="fixed">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="motor_controller"/>
  <origin xyz="-0.11 0 ${chassis_height/2 + 0.03/2}"/>
    </joint>

    <gazebo reference="motor_controller">
        <material>ETABot/Blue</material>
    </gazebo>
```

From the point where the link "motor_controller" will be added, the model will be spawn in Gazebo without any errors but you can't see the robot in the simulator. If I remove the link "motor", the model will be spawn in Gazebo and you can see the robot with the link "motor_controller".

Although the model can't be seen in Gazebo I finished the description of my car-like robot. After finishing I can see the 4 wheels but not the rest of my robot. In rviz is everything allright.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70417/how-to-spawn-urdf.xacro-file-into-gazebo/) by [platzhirsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3129/platzhirsch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-08-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

To spawn a urdf.xacro file in gazebo you have to first convert xacro file using xacro.py script. For example if you have robot.xacro.urdf file in a package called robot_package then following launch file will spawn your robot in Gazebo.

```
<launch>
<!-- Convert xacro and put on parameter server -->
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find robot_package)/urdf/robot.urdf.xacro" />

<!-- Spawn a robot into Gazebo -->
<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model robot" />
</launch>
```

Note: Replace the node and package if you are using simulator_gazebo and not stand alone gazebo accordingly.
Additionally, you can find more details in this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_roslaunch_Files_to_Spawn_Models) and its better to ask gazebo related questions on [Gazebo sim forum](http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/).

To add color in gazebo navigate to the file gazebo.material in materials/scripts folder of your gazebo and include your own color definition. Other colors are defined there you can follow the pattern.
To assign this color to a model use following code in your file.

```
<material>
     <script>Gazebo/yourcolor</script>
</material>
```

Note: This code is for SDF 1.4 change accordingly for your version see documentation here[SDF](http://gazebosim.org/sdf.html).

---

Originally posted by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) with karma: 235 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [platzhirsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3129/platzhirsch/) on 2013-08-01**:
Hi Zee-Q,
many thanks for your help. This was the way I tried to spawn my robot into Gazebo, but if I use macros it doesn't work. Apart form that I'm yousing a xacros-file. Other functions from xacros like constants or math work without any problems. I'm using ROS-Fuerte with Gazebo 1.2.